# Simulate a die with a fixed number of coin tosses.

Tags: probability, dice

I have looked on the internet for a method of simulating a die roll. I have been using [this method](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/29205) which works quite well, but there is a chance after every try that requires me to do it over.

Basically, the method I'm using tells me to treat each coin flip as a bit to make a binary number between $0$ and $2^k$ where $k$ is the number of flips. This is certainly a fair way to simulate a die, but I occasionally have to restart when I get an outcome that is out of range.

Is there a way to simulate an $n$-sided die with a fixed number of coin tosses?

Comment: If you flip some number of fair coins, the total number of possible outcomes is $2^k$ for some positive integer $k$.  Hence the probability of any event is $\ell/2^k$ for some pair of positive integers $\ell$ and $k$.  On the other hand, if you roll a fair six-sided die, there are six equi-probable outcomes, each having probability $1/6$.  What can you say about solutions to the equation $$ \frac{1}{6} = \frac{\ell}{2^k}?$$

Comment: @XanderHenderson

If $k=3$ then $ℓ=\frac{8}{6}$. If $ℓ=1$ then $k=log_2 6$. Since neither approach allows for 2 positive integers, I can only assume that what I'm asking is impossible, or at least with non-powers of 2.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate a fair $n$-sided die with an arbitrary number of sides $n$ using a large number of fair coins, but in the general case you cannot *guarantee* success with a finite number of tosses.

There are a number of methods, but this one captures the key mathematical properties:

Divide $n N$ coins into $n$ groups, one for each possible value of the die.  Toss all the coins and the "winner" is the group that has the most heads.  Clearly this method is unbiased--each die value is equally likely to "win."  You can make $N$ arbitrarily large (say $N = 10^{1000}$) so as to make the probability of a tie negligible.

Negligible... but not zero.

(There are more efficient methods--ones that take fewer tosses on average--but none that guarantee success in a finite number of tosses for an arbitrary $n$.)